# What effects does revving a spin-dash actually accomplish?

Tags: sonic-mania

With the newest addition to the Sonic series, Sonic Mania, there has been a question I've always wanted to ask:

Is there any difference between a single rev spin-dash and one that is revved multiple times? Does revving a spin-dash more times make the character spin-dashing go faster or farther than a spin-dash that isn't revved multiple times? If revving a spin-dash multiple times does have an effect, what exactly is that effect (how much speed and momentum is gained per rev), and at what point do further revs stop increasing this effect?

For the sake of not making this too broad I want to keep this specific to Sonic Mania, as older games might have slightly different answers.

Comment: I would imagine so, mashing spin to go faster is a staple mechanic in Sonic 2 and up. I've only played Mania a little bit so far so I can't be certain but given the heavy amount of nostalgia driving the game's creation I don't see how its possible the devs would change such a core mechanic.

Comment: @Robotnik, honestly I'm pretty sure revving does make the character go faster, but I've never been able to determine to what extent. I've also never been able to determine at what point further mashing has no effect, though I'm 100% positive there is a point where it cuts off; otherwise it would be easy to break the game by simply mashing the button endlessly and then releasing to send the character flying through the level.

Comment: Listen for the sound. Once it's at its highest pitch you've revved as high as it will go

Comment: I had a controller with turbo buttons for my Sega Genesis and I distinctly remember using them to rev because it made a noticable difference. Then again I was like 6 so maybe I was just excited by the sound it made.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 15):

Why not try it out?

Revving the spin dash definitely makes a difference.

Here's a **non-revved spin dash:**

[image: non-revved spin dash]]

And here's a **revved spin dash:**

[image: revved spin dash]

Here's the **drop dash:**

[image: drop dash]

The drop dash appears to be slightly less powerful than a non-revved spin dash, but note that the jump was on a slight hill that caused it to start off with backwards momentum, so they might actually be even.

Here's a **super peel out** without waiting until it's fully charged:

[image: uncharged super peel out]

And here's a fully charged **super peel out:**

[image: charged super peel out]

Normally you'd continue holding right to run at full speed after a super peel out, but without holding right it looks about as powerful as a non-revved spin dash.

Also note that holding right actually slows you down when you're in ball mode!

**Non-revved spin dash, holding right:**

[image]

**Revved spin dash, holding right:**

[image: revved spin dash, holding right]

**Drop dash, holding right:**

[image: drop dash, holding right]

As for how many revs gives you diminishing returns, I think the key is to listen to the sound it makes when you add a rev. Each one causes your "revving noise" to become higher pitched, but only up to a certain point. I think that number is about 7 revs.

Anecdotally, I've noticed that speed-runners jam on the buttons and rev it a bunch of times. And it might be worth noting that in Mirage Saloon zone, the plane will keep up with a non-revved spin dash, but if you rev the spin dash then you'll fall off the plane.

If somebody knows of a better straightaway for testing, I'd be happy to try it out.

---

From the [Speed Demos Archive](https://kb.speeddemosarchive.com/Sonic_the_Hedgehog/Game_Mechanics_and_Glitches#Rolling_and_Spindashing):

> Spindashing has 9 possible speeds, between 8 p/f and 12 p/f in half integers. Every time a button is pressed you add 2 to the base value 8, which then subsequently decreases faster the higher the total value is. Because of this, the minimum requirement to get a 12 speed is 6 button presses, commonly referred to as a "6-tap".
>
> ...
>
> There's no guaranteed way to get a certain spindash speed, so usually runners do 3-taps or other increments in order to get close to the desired speed.

Comment: ...I am tempted to attempt editing these gifs to loop at the same time for easier comparison.

Comment: +1, love the gifs!

Comment: Please note that on May 15, 2023, [Imgur will remove content that is not tied to a user account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/162827). This may affect the media you included in your post since they were not uploaded through SE Imgur. I recommend that you reupload the media through SE Imgur to avoid losing them. You may need to edit the media to make it smaller than 2 MiB, which is the maximum size allowed by SE Imgur.